# How do I programmatically change the body text format on the page content type to full HTML?

Tags: 7, entities, input-formats

I have a custom install profile and I must programmatically change the body text format on the page content type to full HTML. However, I didn't manage to find how to do it.

How can I do it?

Comment: you want to change it for all content types?

Comment: @Aboodred1 only for page (standard type)

Comment: you already created Full HTML format?

Comment: @Aboodred1 yes I did

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with `hook_element_info_alter`, here is a snippet.

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_element_info_alter().
 *
 * Sets the text format processor to a custom callback function.
 * This code is taken from the Better Formats module.
 */
function MODULENAME_element_info_alter(&$type) {
  if (isset($type['text_format']['#process'])) {
    foreach ($type['text_format']['#process'] as &$callback) {
      if ($callback === 'filter_process_format') {
        $callback = 'MODULENAME_filter_process_format';
      }
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Callback for MODULENAME_element_info_alter().
 */
function MODULENAME_filter_process_format($element) {
  $element = filter_process_format($element);
  // Change the default text format of the 'field_company_spotlight' field to
  // 'Media HTML'. 
  if ($element['#bundle'] == 'company' && $element['#field_name'] == 'field_company_spotlight') {
    $element['format']['format']['#default_value'] = 'media_html';
  }
  return $element;
}
?>
```

As [THIS](http://drupal.org/node/1003262#comment-6164084) post suggests you could try

```
$form['field_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#format'] = 'full_html';
$form['field_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#format'] = 'filtered_html';
```

in your `hook_form_alter` or in `hook_FORM_ID_alter`

Also there is [Better Formats](http://drupal.org/project/better_formats) module

> Better formats is a module to add more flexibility to Drupal's core
>   input format system.

Answer (score 2):

Nikhil M's 2nd answer is best -

```
$form['field_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#format'] = 'full_html';
```

no need for hook_element_info

Comment: This belongs in the comment of Nikhil's answer.

Answer (score -1):

you only need one line of code

$result = db_query('UPDATE field_data_body SET body_format='full_html' WHERE `bundle`='page');

Comment: What is wrong with this query? I think it is a workaround...